# Verbal logic problem - running and the weather

Tags: logic

> "If the weather is not fine, then I will not go running."   If the
>   statement above is true. Which of the following statements must also
>   be true?
>
> 1. If I go running, then the weather is fine.
> 2. If I didn't go running, then the weather was not fine.
> 3. If the weather is fine then I will go running
>
> A) 1 only
>   B) 2 only
>   C) 3 only
>   D) 1 and 3
>   E) 2 and 3

---

I'm struggling with this logic problem that I encountered. No matter what I think, all three are correct, but an option for all is not avaliable.

Comment: 1. is true, 2. and 3. are false

Comment: Suppose you run six days a week, weather permitting, and always take Sundays off, regardless of the weather conditions.  Do you see why this eliminates statements 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

let the weather is fine be a event W and going for running be a event R.  I am assuming you know $p\rightarrow q\ =\ \lnot p \lor q$ and $\lnot(\lnot p)=p$.

So given statement is $\lnot W \rightarrow \lnot R\ =\ W\lor \lnot R$

1. is $R\rightarrow W= \lnot R \lor W$ (correct)
2. is $\lnot R \rightarrow \lnot W = R \lor \lnot W$ (not correct)

3 $ W\rightarrow R =\lnot W\lor R$ (not correct).